# "[Amazon][ODBC] (11310) SQL C type not supported." Error while using "Execute SQL Task" with Single Row ResultSet through Redshift

Tags: ssis, odbc, amazon-redshift

I have created a `Execute SQL Task` to query `Redshift` and save the `Single Row resultset` to a variable using `SSIS`. I am using `ODBC` connection and query is as simple as:

```
select 1 as id
```

I have set the `ResultSet` properties to `Single row` and assigned the `Result Name=1` to a variable.

When I execute the task with setting the `Resultset=None` it works with no error but when I execute it with `Resultset=Single row` I see this error:

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: An error occurred while assigning a value to variable "variable_name": "[Amazon][ODBC] (11310) SQL C type not supported.".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution!

I changed **Connection Type = ADO.NET** and used **.Net Providers\Odbc Data Provider** instead of ODBC Connectin and it works perfectly.